# How to annotate text documents with meta-data?

Tags: nlp, metadata, data-cleaning, text-mining

Having a lot of text documents (in natural language, unstructured), what are the possible ways of annotating them with some semantic meta-data? For example, consider a short document:

```
I saw the company's manager last day.
```

To be able to extract information from it, it must be annotated with additional data to be less ambiguous. The process of finding such meta-data is not in question, so assume it is done manually. The question is how to store these data in a way that further analysis on it can be done more conveniently/efficiently?

A possible approach is to use XML tags (see below), but it seems too verbose, and maybe there are better approaches/guidelines for storing such meta-data on text documents.

```
<Person name="John">I</Person> saw the <Organization name="ACME">company</Organization>'s
manager <Time value="2014-5-29">last day</Time>.
```

Comment: One of SGML's major purposes (the same holds for its offspring, XML) was to provide the means for tagging text documents (POS **and** semantic tags).

Comment: Could be more specific/restrictive about what kind of metadata you want to add? With your two examples, I doubt that there is a less verbose way that has the same generic expressiveness as XML tags.

Comment: @ojdo The most of the meta-data is either for disambiguation (like the relative times), or for specifying special entities (i.e. FKs).

Comment: I have used http://brat.nlplab.org/ in the past.  There is a nice interface for many different types of annotations.  The annotations are stored in a separate .annot file which is a list of the words that are annotoated and their position in the document.

Comment: @user1893354 Very helpful! Specially the "[brat standoff format](http://brat.nlplab.org/standoff.html)" used by it seems very suitable to my needs. I suggest posting an answer if you like.

Answer (score 16):

Personally I would advocate using something that is both not-specific to the NLP field, and something that is sufficiently general that it can still be used as a tool even when you've started moving beyond this level of metadata. I would especially pick a format that can be used regardless of development environment and one that can keep some basic structure if that becomes relevant (like tokenization)

It might seem strange, but I would honestly suggest `JSON`. It's extremely well supported, supports a lot of structure, and is flexible enough that you shouldn't have to move from it for not being powerful enough. For your example, something like this:

```
{'text': 'I saw the company's manager last day.", {'Person': [{'name': 'John'}, {'indices': [0:1]}, etc...]}
```

The one big advantage you've got over any NLP-specific formats here is that `JSON` can be parsed in any environment, and since you'll probably have to edit your format anyway, JSON lends itself to very simple edits that give you a short distance to other formats.

You can also implicitly store tokenization information if you want:

```
{"text": ["I", "saw", "the", "company's", "manager", "last", "day."]}
```

EDIT: To clarify the mapping of metadata is pretty open, but here's an example:

```
{'body': '<some_text>',
 'metadata': 
  {'<entity>':
    {'<attribute>': '<value>',
     'location': [<start_index>, <end_index>]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you've got any more questions.

Comment: Being a web developer, JSON seems completely reasonable to me, but, can you elaborate on the exact format of mapping words to entities?

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari Updated answer to include more details.

Answer (score 7):

In general, you don't want to use XML tags to tag documents in this way because tags may overlap.

[UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/), [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) and similar NLP frameworks denote the tags separate from the text.  Each tag, such as `Person`, `ACME`, `John` etc. is stored as the position that the tag begins and the position that it ends.  So, for the tag `ACME`, it would be stored as starting a position 11 and ending at position 17.

Answer (score 7):

The [brat annotation tool](http://brat.nlplab.org/) might be useful for you as per my comment.  I have tried many of them and this is the best I have found.  It has a nice user interface and can support a number of different types of annotations.  The annotations are stored in a separate .annot file which contain each annotation as well as its location within the original document.  A word of warning though, if you ultimately want to feed the annotations into a classifier like the Stanford NER tool then you will have to do some manipulation to get the data into a format that it will accept.

Answer (score 1):

To describe all existed data it is so difficult task, but we can use a data model: http://schema.org/, where are structural types of the information. The prior execution was targeted to implement MarkUp technology, so, it seems can be useful for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Label Studio](https://labelstud.io/playground/?config=%3CView%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%3CHyperTextLabels%20name%3D%22ner%22%20toName%3D%22text%22%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%20%20%3CLabel%20value%3D%22Person%22%20background%3D%22green%22%2F%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%20%20%3CLabel%20value%3D%22Organization%22%20background%3D%22blue%22%2F%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%3C%2FHyperTextLabels%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%22border%3A%201px%20solid%20%23CCC%3B%3Cbr%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20border-radius%3A%2010px%3B%3Cbr%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20padding%3A%205px%22%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%20%20%3CHyperText%20name%3D%22text%22%20value%3D%22%24text%22%2F%3E%3Cbr%3E%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2FView%3E%3Cbr%3E). It supports Simple Text & HTML NER tagging and much more.

[image]

Input to Label Studio for task on the screenshot (HTML code packed to JSON):

```
{
    "text": "<div style=\"max-width: 750px\"><div style=\"clear: both\"><div style=\"float: right; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #F2F3F4; background-color: #F8F9F9; border-radius: 5px; padding: 7px; margin: 10px 0;\"><p><b>Jules</b>: No no, Mr. Wolfe, it's not like that. Your help is definitely appreciated.</p></div></div><div style=\"clear: both\"><div style=\"float: right; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #F2F3F4; background-color: #F8F9F9; border-radius: 5px; padding: 7px; margin: 10px 0;\"><p><b>Vincent</b>: Look, Mr. Wolfe, I respect you. I just don't like people barking orders at me, that's all.</p></div></div><div style=\"clear: both\"><div style=\"display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #D5F5E3; background-color: #EAFAF1; border-radius: 5px; padding: 7px; margin: 10px 0;\"><p><b>The Wolf</b>: If I'm curt with you, it's because time is a factor. I think fast, I talk fast, and I need you two guys to act fast if you want to get out of this. So pretty please, with sugar on top, clean the car.</p></div></div></div>"
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "9fkAdIXgkV",
        "from_name": "ner",
        "to_name": "text",
        "source": "$text",
        "type": "hypertextlabels",
        "value": {
            "start": "/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/b[1]/text()[1]",
            "end": "/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/b[1]/text()[1]",
            "text": "Jules",
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 5,
            "htmllabels": [
                "Person"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "YMeGv8ndLx",
        "from_name": "ner",
        "to_name": "text",
        "source": "$text",
        "type": "hypertextlabels",
        "value": {
            "start": "/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/text()[1]",
            "end": "/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[1]/text()[1]",
            "text": "Wolfe",
            "startOffset": 13,
            "endOffset": 18,
            "htmllabels": [
                "Organization"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "vgGGhXRFcr",
        "from_name": "ner",
        "to_name": "text",
        "source": "$text",
        "type": "hypertextlabels",
        "value": {
            "start": "/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/text()[1]",
            "end": "/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/text()[1]",
            "text": " Look, Mr. Wo",
            "startOffset": 1,
            "endOffset": 14,
            "htmllabels": [
                "Person"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "oJxIH-ztQv",
        "from_name": "ner",
        "to_name": "text",
        "source": "$text",
        "type": "hypertextlabels",
        "value": {
            "start": "/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/text()[2]",
            "end": "/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/text()[2]",
            "text": "people bar",
            "startOffset": 38,
            "endOffset": 48,
            "htmllabels": [
                "Organization"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```