# Are there any annotators or Named Entity Recognition for license plate numbers?

Tags: text-mining

Most vehicle license/number plate extractors I've found involve reading a plate from an image (OCR) but I'm interested in something that could tag instances of license plates in a body of text. Are there any such annotators out there?

Comment: Any particular country? Different countries have different license plate formats. Its a big world out there.

Comment: @Spacedman Any country is fine :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of pretty decent tools out there for text annotation in general, and given the broad nature of the task you're approaching (license plates are about as general as words), the annotation tools you are looking at should probably come from the more classical tools for annotation.

There was actually a pretty good discussion about annotation tools on [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-to-annotate-text-documents-with-meta-data/404#404) question, which should actually apply to this problem. The most relied-upon thing in annotation right now is probably `brat`. You can learn more about `brat` [here](http://brat.nlplab.org/).

Hope that helps! Let me know if you've got any more questions.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using `regular expressions`.

2 letters followed by a number (\d denotes digits) would be

```
[A-Z]{2} \d*
```

2 or 3 letters followed by a number is

```
[A-Z]{2,3} \d*
```

Comment: I don't mean to be negative, but regular expressions are an extremely poor choice for this problem. Between state-by-state variation, vanity plates, and differing formats, regular expressions are a poor choice.

Comment: How many different variations are there? I'm from a different country.

Comment: A conservative estimate would be 51, probably close to a few hundred.

Comment: Ah right I see the problem. I was thinking that I could find all the plates registered here with 3 regular expressions.

Comment: @germcd Thanks for the attempt though! Glad to hear I wasn't the only person to think of regex too.